# Presidential vs Parliamentary system of governmet

Tags: form-of-government

Do we differentiate the title of the leader of a parliamentary system as (Prime Minister) from the title of the leader of a presidential system as (President)?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about your thinking? I'm trying to piece together an answer, but it isn't clear where you are coming form.

Comment: What I want to ask is that,"Prime Minister" is a title for the leader chosen through Parliamentary System and "President" the title of a leader chosen through a presidential system?

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, no. The most basic reason is that leaders aren't named that way. Each country has a name for its leadership that may not have anything to do with it's structure.

The best advice is to find out what the leader is called in their nation, and use that term.

### Multiple Leaders

One practical reason this doesn't work is that many nations have multiple leaders.  [South Korea](http://english1.president.go.kr/government/executive-branch.php) and [Uzbekistan](https://www.uzbekistan.org/uzbekistan/political/#government) are sometimes used as non-European examples of a presidential system, but they both have a president *and* a prime minister.

### An Unclear Dichotomy

A second practical concern would be that there will be many cases where the presidential/parliamentary classification breaks down. For example, there are [semi-presidential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-presidential_system) states - do you expect them to have a president or a prime minister?

### The Titles Themselves

Finally, you might also run into problems working backwards. That is to say, if you know a leader is called 'President' you might think that means they come from a presidential system.  However, many dictators have that title also.  This further obscures the relationship between the structure of a government and the titles that leadership use.

Comment: @AlexanderSmithAmoakoMaxwell - You are welcome! If this answered your question, please consider accepting it.